# Squared increments of Brownian motion in $L^2$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I have encountered an $L^2$ limit, which I am not sure of:

Let $B_t$ be a Brownian motion and $a=t_0<t_1<\dots <t_n=b$. Show that

$$\lim_{max(t_{i+1}-t_i)\mapsto 0} \sum_{0\leq i \leq n-1} (B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i})^2 = b-a \hspace{1cm}\text{ in } L^2.$$

Is there an elegant way to show this?

Comment: you have a sum of independents, you have the distribution of the $(B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i})^2$.  a straightforward computation is not bad at all.  there is an elegant way when the partitions are refining, but it's not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\Pi=\{a=t_0<t_1 < \ldots < t_n=b\}$ a partition of $[a,b]$ and $$S_2^{\Pi}(B) := \sum_{0 \leq i \leq n-1} (B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})^2$$ Then $$\mathbb{E}S_2^{\Pi}(B) = \sum_{0 \leq i \leq n-1} (t_{i+1}-t_i) = b-a$$

since $B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i} \sim N(0,t_{i+1}-t_i)$. Thus

$$\begin{align} \mathbb{E}\big((S_2^{\Pi}(B)-(b-a))^2 \big) &= \text{var}(S_2^{\Pi}) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \underbrace{\text{var}((B(t_{j+1})-B(t_j)^2)}_{\mathbb{E} \bigg( \big( (B(t_{j+1})-B(t_j))^2-(t_{j+1}-t_j) \big)^2 \bigg)} \tag{1} \\ &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \mathbb{E} \bigg( \big( B(t_{j+1}-t_j)^2-(t_{j+1}-t_j) \big)^2 \bigg) \\ &\stackrel{B_t \sim \sqrt{t} \cdot B_1}{=} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (t_{j+1}-t_j)^2 \cdot \underbrace{\mathbb{E}((B_1^2-1)^2)}_{2} \\ &\leq 2 \cdot \max_j (t_{j+1}-t_j) \cdot (b-a) \to 0 \qquad \text{as} \, \max_i (t_{j+1}-t_j) \to 0 \end{align}$$

where we used the independence of the increments in $(1)$.

Comment: How did you compute te expectation value?

Comment: @Hendrra Which one...?

Comment: Sorry, I should have pointed which one. I meant this one: $\mathbb{E}S_2^{\Pi}(B)$.

Comment: @Hendrra Just interchange $\mathbb{E}$ with the finite sum (using linearity of the expectation) and then use $\mathbb{E}((B_t-B_s)^2) = t-s$ (which follows from $B_t-B_s \sim N(0,t-s)$).

Comment: Thanks. One more thing -- how do we know that $\mathbb{E}((B_t-B_s)^2) = t-s$?

Comment: @Hendrra For a Gaussian random variable $X$ with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$ it holds that $\mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sigma^2$. Use this for $X := B_t-B_s$.

Comment: Thanks for your time and clear explanation! Now I got it :)

Comment: @saz if I wanna show that $\lim_{max(t_{i+1}-t_i)\mapsto 0} \sum_{0\leq i \leq n-1} B_{s_i}(B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i})$ exists in $L^2$ but that depends on the choice of $t_i\le s_i\le t_{i+1}$, in particular taking e.g. $s_i=t_i$ or $s_i=t_{i+1}$. It is sufficient that I apply the same your procedure? namely finding E[$B_{s_i}(B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i})]$ (supposing that is a good fit as $L^2$-Limit) and then check If actually converge in $L^2$?

Comment: @Alias__ No, it won't work. For the quadratic variance, it does work because the $L^2$-limit is deterministic. This is not true for the $L^2$-limit of the sum $\sum_i B_{s_i}(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$.

Comment: @saz ok I worked a little bit on it and I found out that: $\lim_{max(t_{i+1}-t_i)\mapsto 0} \sum_{0\leq i \leq n-1} B_{t_i}(B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i}) = \frac12(B^2_t-t)$ in probability (because the convergence to the quadratic variation is in probability). Then computing $limE[\sum_{0\leq i \leq n-1} B_{t_i}(B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i}) - \frac12(B^2_t-t)]$ I can show that the expectation is $0$ (all the term cancel out).

Comment: Finally I can conclude that $\lim_{max(t_{i+1}-t_i)\mapsto 0} \sum_{0\leq i \leq n-1} B_{t_i}(B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i}) = \frac12(B^2_t-t)$ in $L^2$. Is it correct this procedure? then doing the same with $B_{s_i}=B_{t_{i+1}}$ i will find out a different $L^2$ limit.

Comment: @Alias__ I recommend opening a new question (or searching for an old one with the same question) because this is not the topic of this question here. The limit of your sum depends on the chosen intermediate value $s_i \in [t_i,t_{i+1}]$; look up the Stratonovich integral. You can also take a look at this [solution manual](http://www.motapa.de/brownian_motion/solutions-bm-2ed.pdf) (Problem 15.15)

Comment: @saz thank you saz, one clarification (I'm sorry if it is not the right place but has no sense now open a new post): in problem 15.15 why he computes the Variance of Z? I guess that it correspond to compute E[$Z^2$] since E[Z]=0, but taking the variance allow to avoid the problem of the double sum in $Z^2$. is this the reason? And then why it compute E[Y]? he is like "guessing" that the $L^2-Limit$ is exactly E[Y] (that then could be actually prove it). is my interpretation right?

Comment: @Alias__ a) Sometimes $L^2$-convergence is easier to prove than $L^1$-convergence because $L^2$-sums allow you to take advantage of the independence of the increments. b) For $Y$ the reasoning is similar to that in this question here... so yes, computing $\mathbb{E}(Y)$ helps to get an idea what the limit might be.